# Consider a normal curve with $p(X<13)=p(X>7)\approx 0.9332$. What is the mean value?

Tags: probability, proof-verification

> The following picture represents a Gauss curve with
>   $p(X<13)=p(X>7)\approx0.9332$. Find the mean value.
>
> [image]

I've been trying to solve this for a while and then I did $(13+7)/2 = 10$. My book states the solution is 10, but doesn't show the steps.

Did I solve this correctly? It seems to easy to be true.

Comment: Yeah, your reasoning is fine. Normal distributions are symmetric around the mean. So if the regions bounded left of $13$ or right of $7$ are equal (i.e. the probabilities) then the mean should be halfway between $7$ and $13$

Comment: @Jam Right, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that seems fine using symmetry.

Roundaboutly, let $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, $p = 0.9332$, let $\Phi$ be the standard normal CDF.

By standardizing, we have
$$P(X< 13) = P\left(Z<\frac{13-\mu}{\sigma}\right) =  \Phi\left(\frac{13-\mu}{\sigma}\right) =  p$$
which implies that $\frac{13-\mu}{\sigma}= \Phi^{-1}(p) = 1.5$ by using a calculator.

Similary,
$$P(X>7) = 1-P(X<7) = 1-\Phi\left(\frac{7-\mu}{\sigma}\right) = p$$
which implies $\frac{7-\mu}{\sigma} = \Phi^{-1}(1-p) = -1.5$. Solving the system gives $\mu = 10$ and $\sigma = 2$.